# How bonjour discover devices on network?

Tags: c, bonjour

I want to write a C program that can search [Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29) enabled devices on network.

Basically we have a Network IP Camera, it supports Bonjour protocol. I want to write API in C that can search these devices which have Bonjour enabled. Does anyone have sample code or suggestions on how should I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following links provide some code samples, as you requested:

[mDNSResponder](https://github.com/jevinskie/mDNSResponder)

Quotes from mDNSPosix/ReadMe.txt:

> mDNSPosix is a port of Apple's Multicast DNS and DNS Service Discovery
>   code to Posix platforms.
>
> Multicast DNS and DNS Service Discovery are technologies that allow
>   you to register IP-based services and browse the network for those
>   services.
>
> Packing List:
>
> The sample uses the following directories:
>
> o mDNSCore -- A directory containing the core mDNS code. This code
>   is written in pure ANSI C and has proved to be very portable.   Every
>   platform needs this core protocol engine code.
>
> o mDNSShared -- A directory containing useful code that's not core to 
>   the main protocol engine itself, but nonetheless useful, and used by
>   more than one (but not necessarily all) platforms.
>
> o mDNSPosix -- The files that are specific to Posix platforms: Linux, 
>   Solaris, FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD, etc. This code will also work on
>   OS X, though that's not its primary purpose.
>
> o Clients -- **Example client code showing how to use the API to the
>
>   services provided by the daemon.**
>
> Using the Sample
>   ---------------- When you compile, you will get:
>
> o Main products for general-purpose use (e.g. on a desktop computer):
>     - mdnsd
>     - libmdns
>     - nss_mdns (See nss_ReadMe.txt for important information about nss_mdns)
>
> o **Standalone products for dedicated devices (printer, network camera,
>   etc.)**
>     - mDNSClientPosix
>     - mDNSResponderPosix
>     - mDNSProxyResponderPosix
>
> o Testing and Debugging tools
>     - dns-sd command-line tool (from the "Clients" folder)
>     - mDNSNetMonitor
>     - mDNSIdentify

[SDWrap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxservdisc/files)

> ReadMe:
>
> Quite simple wrapper app to execute some command with Zeroconf
>   supplied addresses and ports. Uses wxWidgets and wxServDisc for
>   service discovery...

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. But in the given link I could not find any source code which I can use to search bonjour devices on the network.

Comment: Have you read the [ReadMe.txt](https://github.com/jevinskie/mDNSResponder/blob/2942dde61f920fbbf96ff9a3840567ebbe7cb1b6/mDNSPosix/ReadMe.txt) for your platform? Quote: "When you compile, you will get: Standalone products for dedicated devices (printer, network camera, etc.)"

I did a quick read-through of the source code. It's heavily commented, and if you take the time to use the ReadMe for your specific platform as a guide I think you'll find exactly what you're looking for.